# How to add custom attributes for items in a CheckBoxList?

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement of showing the check box list. And for each check box item, I have to store a custom attribute (apart from text and value) which I will use to compare in button click event.

Please suggest me better approach

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate the custom value with the value of the checkbox separating them with a well-known character or set of chearacters.
You can then retrieve and split values from the request.